# how to retrive data from 4 tables with complex conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

i have these 4 tables

```
1. course 
------------------------ 
CourseID   CourseNum    CourseName             

2. courseRequirements
------------------------
CourseNum  ReqNum                

3. semestercourses
------------------------
CourseID                

4. studentcoursecomplete
-----------------------
CourseID   StudentID
```

i don't know how to start and do the sql statement
the statement must do the folowing

1-show the course name from table course where course.CourseID=semestercourses.CourseID
2-don't show the course that student complete "studentcoursecomplete"
3-don't show the course that have a requirement that student didn't finish

example

this semester there are 3 courses (english 2,math,sport)
john is a student
he complete the math course (studentcoursecomplete)
english 2 have a requirement "english 1"(courseRequirements)  and he didn't finish english1 (studentcoursecomplete)
so he can see just "math" course

what is the select statement that do this !!!!

Comment: You could start from this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp

Comment: hhhhh basic select statement ^_^ i know that bro ..

Comment: So we do your homework?

Comment: that's not a homework .. i am work on my website and i have a problem with this statement

Answer (score 0):

Just a Guess (based on what you say) but I think LEFT JOINS may help you. The issue is having to include rows that do not exist in the other tables, the basic format would be something like this:

```
SELECT course.* 
FROM course
LEFT JOIN studentcoursecomplete ON studentcoursecomplete.CourseID = course.CourseID
LEFT JOIN courseRequirements ON courseRequirements.CourseNum = course.CourseNum
WHERE courseRequirements.CourseNum IS NULL 
AND studentcoursecomplete.CourseID IS NULL
```

The left joins will give all the rows from the left table with all the matching rows in the right table and NULL in columns from the right table where there is not a match. Hence you can test for the NULLs to find where there is no match in the right table.

This is not necessarily the full solution but will hopefully give you some ideas to play around with.

Comment: it's work fine ^_^ but one thing less 
if there is a course english2 and the student complete english1 .. english 2 must be shown .. how can make it

Comment: I would have thought that should work given that Course English2 should have a unique ID to Course English1, so English1 (completed) would return columns from studentcoursecomplete and English2 (not completed) would return NULLs.